# What is the default font height used in the API CreateFont ? How does it choose a font face?

Tags: winapi, fonts

I patched some code to make it DPI aware

`font = CreateFont (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, FIXED_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE, TEXT ("FixedSys"));`

became

`font = CreateFont ([some scaled value], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, FIXED_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE, TEXT ("FixedSys"));`

I don't understand the behaviour if height = 0 (first argument)

According to MS

> 0
>   The font mapper uses a default height value when it searches for a match.

What is the default height value?
I've got a Korean customer complaining that the text in the app has shrunk markedly between the old code (height = 0) and the new (height = 14) at 100% scaling. On a UK OS the text appears identical.

And a different font is used by the mapper.

Comment: Might depend on the font.

Comment: It depends in fact of the font. So when you want to have a constant user experience need need to define a font height by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you [need this code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createfonta). Font height is calculated by this formula `nHeight = -MulDiv(PointSize, GetDeviceCaps(hDC, LOGPIXELSY), 72);`

`PointSize` - is a font size, `GetDeviceCaps(hDC, LOGPIXELSY)` is a call to get DPI via GDI (old stuff).

In my DPI awareness battle I use this code:

`fontStruct.lfHeight = 0 - MulDiv( height, GetWindowDpi( window ), 72 );`

`GetWindowDpi` is a wrapper that call `GetDpiForWindow` for windows 10 or `GetDpiForMonitor` for Windows 8.1 or use same old stuff `GetDeviceCaps(hDC, LOGPIXELSY)` for Windows 7.

Comment: I guess this is more of a platform issue than a coding one - I have code to get an appropriate height (much like your example) but its producing something much smaller than our Korean user used to have when we specified height as 0.

Comment: Ask user to supply Korean font name and check, default value is system font dependent and can be received via [GetTextMetrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-gettextmetrics) for a DC where you didn't set your own font.